# Does anyone know a rationally chain connected, Cohen Macaulay variety which is not separably rationally connected?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

An $ n $-dimensional variety (here variety means an integral, separated, scheme of finite type over an algebraically closed field) $ X $ over a field $ k $ is rational if there is a birational map $ \phi: \mathbb{P}^{n}_{k} \dashrightarrow X $.

A variety $ X $ over a field $ k $ is separably rationally connected if there is a dominant, separable, generically finite, rational map $ \phi: Y \times \mathbb{P}^{1}_{k} \dashrightarrow X $ such that the diagonal map $ (\phi,\phi): Y \times \mathbb{P}^{1}_{k} \times \mathbb{P}^{1}_{k} \dashrightarrow X \times X $ is dominant.

A variety $ X $ is rationally chain connected if for any two points $ x_{1},x_{2} \in X $ there is a collection of rational curves $ \{C_{i}\}_{i=1}^{\ell} $ such that $ x_{1} \in C_{1} $, $ C_{i} \cap C_{i+1} \ne \oslash $ and $ x_{2} \in C_{\ell} $.

Does anyone know of a rationally chain connected, Cohen Macaulay variety which is not separably rationally connected?  I suspect that there is such a variety, but can not think of an example.
The Cohen Macaulay condition rules out the classic example of a cone over an elliptic curve, as the condition that the depth of the maximal ideal of the vertex of the cone be two implies that the local ring of vertex would be a regular local ring.  Therefore the Cohen Macaulay condition rules out this example.

I suspect that some similar example will work, but I cannot think of one off-hand.

Comment: There are examples of unirational K3 surfaces in positive characteristic due to Shioda. Since these have  nonzero 2-forms, they won't be seperably rationally connected. Perhaps you wanted an example in char 0?

Comment: I am confused. If $f(x,y,z)=0$ is the equation of a smooth cubic in $\mathbb{P}^2$, then $k[x,y,z]/f(x,y,z)$ is a cone over a genus $1$ curve, and it is a complete intersection, hence Cohen-Macaulay. What did I miss?

Comment: @DavidESpeyer  Thank you.  For a faulty reason I thought that the Cohen Macaulay condition ruled out the classic example.

Comment: @DonuArapura  Thank you for the example of Shioda's unirational K3 surfaces.

Comment: There are some positive results about rational connectedness of the smooth locus of singular varieties that satisfy a (stronger) variant of rational connectedness for the entire variety.  The main such result is the theorem of Keel and McKernan that the smooth locus of a weak del Pezzo surface is rationally connected.